# Alignment inside command \boxed

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I need a little help,! I have some problems to put more than 1 sentence, jumping lines inside the command `\boxed`, then i discovered how to do it, but i have so problems in allignment inside the box, i can't allign sentences to the left inside this comand :

```
\boxed{
\begin{array}{clr}
n \Leftrightarrow \textrm{ energia}\\
l \Leftrightarrow \textrm{ momento angular}\\
m \Leftrightarrow \textrm{ componente z do momento angular}\\
s \Leftrightarrow \textrm{ spin}
\end{array}}
```

I tried this ideas, but none of them worked

```
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{align}
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\boxed{
\begin{array}{l}
n \Leftrightarrow \textrm{ energia}\\
l \Leftrightarrow \textrm{ momento angular}\\
m \Leftrightarrow \textrm{ componente z do momento angular}\\
s \Leftrightarrow \textrm{ spin}
\end{array}}


\boxed{
\begin{array}{rl}
n & \Leftrightarrow \textrm{ energia}\\
l & \Leftrightarrow \textrm{ momento angular}\\
m & \Leftrightarrow \textrm{ componente z do momento angular}\\
s & \Leftrightarrow \textrm{ spin}
\end{array}}

\end{document}
```

The first code gives you left aligened contents of the box (using `{l}`). As you can see in the following image, the output looks quite strange, so it would be better, to additionally align all the arrows. This is done in the second example, where I have used the `&` as an alignment character, while contents left of it are right alined and contents right of it are right aligned (`{rl}`).

[image]